# Need help with While loop

Tags: programming

I'm trying to do the iterative jacobian method but I can't get the output. Any other alternatives using iterative jacobian would be highly appreciated.

```
counter = 1; loopiter = 5;
While[True,
  θest = {Part[θi, 1, 1], Part[θi, 2, 1], 
  Part[θi, 3, 1]};
  θ1 = Part[θest, 1, 1]; θ2 = Part[θest, 2, 1]; 
  θ3 = Part[θest, 3, 1];
  pnew = p0T;
  dP = pG - pnew;
  Jnew = J0trans;
  dθ = Inverse (Jnew).dP;
  θi = θest + dθ;
  If[counter > loopiter, Break[]]; 
  counter++];
  Print["θi = ", MatrixForm[θi]]
```

where

```
p0T = 
  (Cos[θ1] (0.3 + Cos[θ2] (0.3 + 0.15 Cos[θ3]) - 0.15 Sin[θ2] Sin[θ3])
     Sin[θ1] (0.3 + Cos[θ2] (0.3 + 0.15 Cos[θ3]) - 0.15 Sin[θ2] Sin[θ3])
     0.3 Sin[θ2] + 0.15 Sin[θ2 + θ3]

1.

pG = {0.35, 0.05, 0.35}

J0trans = 
  (-Sin[θ1] 
    (0.3 + Cos[θ2] (0.3 + 0.15 Cos[θ3]) - 0.15 Sin[θ2] Sin[θ3]) Cos[θ1] 
    (-(0.3 + 0.15 Cos[θ3]) Sin[θ2] - 0.15 Cos[θ2] Sin[θ3]) Cos[θ1] 
    (-0.15 Cos[θ3] Sin[θ2] - 0.15 Cos[θ2] Sin[θ3]) Cos[θ1] 
    (0.3 + Cos[θ2] (0.3 + 0.15 Cos[θ3]) - 0.15 Sin[θ2] Sin[θ3]) Sin[θ1] 
    (-(0.3 + 0.15 Cos[θ3]) Sin[θ2] - 0.15 Cos[θ2] Sin[θ3]) Sin[θ1] 
    (-0.15 Cos[θ3] Sin[θ2] - 0.15 Cos[θ2] Sin[θ3])

0   

0.3 Cos[θ2]+0.15 Cos[θ2+θ3]  0.15 Cos[θ2+θ3]))
```

Comment: Please ensure that the code in the question can be simply copy-pasted. As it stands, I cannot get your code to run, which makes it very hard to help you. Furthermore, please be a bit more specific than "I can't get the output" - what are you expecting?

Comment: Your code has syntax errors and undefined variables. Unless these simple errors are corrected by you, there is not much we can do to help you with your code.

Comment: I figured it out. I used a for loop instead